# Change Facebook login dialog layout

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I'm making an app which has facebook login in it. now the challenge I'm facing is that there are few things to be added to the login dialog which pops up after clicking on Log in with Facebook Button.

I'm using facebook sdk 4.10.1
The required changes are as follows:-

1) circled text is to be changed to

```
    Log in to use your Facebook account with ** SOME APP**
```

[image]

2) the app logo is to be inserted below the above mentioned text at the center.

3) the dialog size of login page is to be changed

desired text type

[image]

as you can see the text in the following image the text is changed

Hope someone can help

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any reason to customize the facebook login dialog... That's how the users expect to login with facebook and thats how it's done at all apps.

Comment: That is not possible. As @Juvi already says, users know this dialog, and it is important it looks consistent across all apps, so that users can easily recognize it as being “official”. Everything else would just make the whole thing less secure, in terms of phishing attacks etc. // What your screenshot shows appears not to be the login to your app (where the user grants permissions), but the login to Facebook itself only – even more reason for not allowing you to change anything about it. Your app’s logo should show up as soon as it gets to the part where it actually is about login to your app

Comment: I've updated the question . this is the screenshot of one of the facebook login page. and My client is forcing me to make it look somehow this way. even I've explained him many times that this is not possible but he sends me the screenshots of different screens, showing me that people have altered it already.